# Xamarin Map crashes when I load page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

**EDIT : PROBLEM IS FIXED FOR ANDROID, I FORGOT TO ADD THE API KEY TO METADATA**

I'm trying to add a map to my Xamarin project for Anroid and UWP, but when my page with the map is done loading the app crashes and the only exception message I get is:

`An unhandled exception occured. occurred`

I tried to find the solution by going through the code with breakpoints, but it seemed to just go through the code fine and immediatly after that it threw the exception again.

This problem seems to happen everytime and on each platform (haven't tested iOS, but I'm not gonna use it anyway), while I followed the tutorial from Xamarin on Xamarin.Forms.Maps.

This is the code for the .xaml.cs file (the part that is commented out is another approach I tried with the same results):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MuffinAppHybrid
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Map map = new Map(
            //MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            //        new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
            //{
            //    IsShowingUser = true,
            //    HeightRequest = 100,
            //    WidthRequest = 960,
            //    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            //};
            //StackLayout stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
            //stack.Children.Add(map);
            //Content = stack;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the .xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="MuffinAppHybrid.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">
            <maps:Map WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
            x:Name="MyMap"
            IsShowingUser="true"
            MapType="Street"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I'm really not sure what's going wrong since the exception message tells practically nothing. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1 - Print Screen of LogCat:**
[image]

**EDIT 2 - Navigation to Page:**

The problem could also be located at the navigation to the Map page, that code is found here:

```
private async void GoToMap(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPage page = new MapPage();
    page.Title = "Muffin Map";
    await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

Comment: if you test on Android I think you can have some info with logcat

Comment: have you used try/catch?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro where can I find the logcat?

Comment: @Jason, no but I could try it on the commented out code

Comment: there are multiple posts on SO about catching unhandled exceptions, as well as services like HockeyApp and Mobile Center that will help you log them

Comment: in Android Device Monitor. in Visual Studio is under Tools -> Android... in VS4Mac... I don't remember... one of menus...

Comment: @Jason I tried a try/catch, nothing was caught, and I still got the exception

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro I've added a print screen of my logcat (just the errors and warnings)

Comment: have you follow these https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro Yes, I've followed those

Comment: I don't know. You can try to download https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/ and take a look to differences with your prj

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro I made changes to project based on the WorkingWithMaps project (which worked), but I still have the same problem